# Using IBM Watson Conversation from an API in C#

Tags: c#, api, bots, watson-conversation

I am developing an API that will be consumed by a mobile app that I am developing. In this app, I want to use the IBM Watson Conversation to create a bot that will "talk" to my end user. I created the workspace on the Watson Conversation environment. However, I don't know, and I cannot find an example, in C#, where the code is "calling" the conversation.

So, does anyone have any example of how can I use the Watson conversation from my c# Api?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this SDK Experimental, with it we did some demos in asp.net C # and bluemix.

SDK Experiemental: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Watson.SDK.Core/

Other
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud

Comming soon, it will avaliable.